Cant loop through a for loop to click on element - webdriver io
I have below code and it will dynamically inject optionName to a xpath.
And try to click on it.
getSortOptionByName(optionName: string) {
    return $(`//android.widget.Button[@content-desc="${optionName}"]`);
  }

Below is the full code.
  public async selectingEachSortOption(): Promise<void>
  {
    const sortOptions = await this.getAllTheAvailableSortOptions();
    for(const sortItem of sortOptions){

       await (await this.getSortOptionByName(sortItem)).waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 5000 });
       await (await this.getSortOptionByName(sortItem)).waitForEnabled({ timeout: 5000 });
       await (await this.getSortOptionByName(sortItem)).click();
       this.clickOnSortByDropDown();
    }
  }

When I use this code in my test, It will iterate through the 1st loop.(I have 4 loops)
But at the 2nd loop, it will end with no errors and the test will mark as pass.
What are the possible mistakes I'm doing here?

Your interactions with the UI on the first loop may affect the UI itself, making the further loops invalid. To explore this, I suggest creating 4 variables with each item of the loop and then debug the state of each variable while you do the steps of the loop against each of them - you may find that after the first clicks, the other elements are unavailable.

Yep, I tried with 4 variable approach and now it's working.

Thanks ChathuD. I made my comment as an Answer. To inform other that this approach can help, can you mark the Answer as accepted?

Your interactions with the UI on the first loop may affect the UI itself, making the further loops invalid. To explore this, I suggest creating 4 variables with each item of the loop and then debug the state of each variable while you do the steps of the loop against each of them - you may find that after the first clicks, the other elements are unavailable.
